# powershell - pass dynamic token value to an Rest API URL reading from csv file

Tags: powershell, rest

I am trying to make a REST API call through powershell as below. I would like to pass dynamic values for **token** reading through a csv or text file.

Any help is much appreciated!

```
$user = 'username'
$pass = 'password'
$pair = "$($user):$($pass)"
$encodedCreds = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($pair))
$basicAuthValue = "Basic $encodedCreds"
$Params = @{
 "URI"     = '<domain>/api/v1/validate-token?transactionId=486275931&**token**=741963&sourceIdentifier=IND&partnerId=159753&aggregatorId=852963741'
 "Method"  = 'GET'
 "Headers" = @{
 Authorization = $basicAuthValue
 token = 
 }
}
```

Comment: "Dynamic values" based on what?

Comment: You could try going for something like `"token" = $(Get-Content .\test.txt)`
If you're going to get it from csv - you could try `Import-Csv` cmdlet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean to replace the token (and perhaps also other variables) in the URI as well as in the `token =` value, you need to either use double-quote characters around the uri string or use the more elegant (IMO) `-f` Format operator

Suppose your CSV looks anything like this:

```
partnerId,aggregatorId,transactionId,token
159753,852963741,486275931,123456
888888,999999999,789789789,654321
```

Then you can do:

- This is using double-quotes and `$()` [Subexpressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.1#subexpression-operator--)

```
Import-Csv -Path '<path\to\the\file.csv>' | ForEach-Object {
    $Params = @{
        "URI"     = "<domain>/api/v1/validate-token?transactionId=$($_.transactionId)&token=$($_.token)&sourceIdentifier=IND&partnerId=$($_.partnerId)&aggregatorId=$($_.aggregatorId)"
        "Method"  = 'GET'
        "Headers" = @{
            Authorization = $basicAuthValue
            token         = $_.token
        }
    }

    # the rest of your code
}
```

OR

- Use the `-f` [Format operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.1#format-operator--f)

```
# for readability create a template URI string where the variables from the CSV are to be inserted
$url = '<domain>/api/v1/validate-token?transactionId={0}&token={1}&sourceIdentifier=IND&partnerId={2}&aggregatorId={3}'

Import-Csv -Path '<path\to\the\file.csv>' | ForEach-Object {
    $Params = @{
        "URI"     = $url -f $_.transactionId, $_.token, $_.partnerId, $_.aggregatorId
        "Method"  = 'GET'
        "Headers" = @{
            Authorization = $basicAuthValue
            token         = $_.token
        }
    }

    # the rest of your code
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked exactly as expected.